# Code-OSS doesn't open folder or files from terminal command 'code-oss .'

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, kali-linux

A few days ago I installed Kali Linux. I'm trying to use Code-OSS instead of VSCode, since newest version of Kali doesn't have the libraries needed to install the normal one.

If I try to open a folder in Code-OSS from terminal using `code-oss .` or `code .`, it just opens Code on a new 'untitled-1' document, or opens the folder I was before closing Code-OSS. It doesn't open the folder I was in the terminal.

In these cases I need to open the folder I want through File > Open folder > search for folder and then open it.

The same just occurred with `git commit` or `git commit --amend`; it opens a new document, not the one I want to open.

I spent sometime searching for a solution on documentation, stackoverflow, google but could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find any way to resolve this problem on Code-oss. Apparently it happened just with me.

Surprisingly for me, I was able to install VSCode following this [tutorial](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-kali-linux/), and it apparently managed to ignore the lack of libraries of Kali Linux that I mentioned above.

I hope this solution prevent any person in the future to get stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I first installed Kali-linux on my VM. Pretty anoying.

Just intall vscode by running :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install code
```

It will unistall code-oss and install VsCode, and it works now.

Comment: I think it was a problem with Kali recent release at that time. 
As I said in the first paragraph, normal VSCode (which I already tried to install) was the one that wasn't working properly. I was using Code-OSS for that reason. 
Anyways, thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on Arch Linux. After several attempts, I found that adding the `-w` parameter works:

```
code -w your-file
```